# resize array in for loop in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I need to run this loop and add the values to the length array each time the loop iterates, so far each time i loop the temp array is cleared so the data is getting lost each iteration. I want to resize the array and add the user input to the length array each iteration.

```
int[] lengthArray = new int [1];


for (int i = 0; i < lengthArray.Length; i++)
{
    lengthArray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] temp = new int [lengthArray.Length + 1] ;
    temp[i] = lengthArray[i];
    lengthArray = temp;

}
```

Comment: You want it to run forever?

Comment: Use [`Array.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-7.0)  to resize the array?

Comment: Or use a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store your result in a `List<int>` instead of an array `int[]` .

Then you each time you want to add an element in the `lengthArray` you can just call the `Add` method.